# Trouble with tcommand mkspline and time variable that is a daily date

Tags: date, stata, spline

I need to create splines in Stata for a spline regression, with the knot being the (daily) date of a terrorist attack and `spline_before` being the interviews (in days) conducted before the attack and `spline_after` being the interviews after the attack.

This is my code so far:

```
mkspline spline_before 20808 spline_after = interviewend
```

"20808" is the numeric value of the date of the attack that Stata works with, as Stata implements dates as days since 1.1.1960.

This is where the problem lies. The values of the variable `spline_before` are too large, because of how Stata works with dates (20695-20808). `spline_after` works fine, probably because its starting point is the knot (20808).

I am guessing that to solve the problem either I need to set a starting point for `spline_before` or I need to get Stata to work with actual dates, rather than the numeric values.

I tried converting `interviewend` into date format:

```
gen interviewend = mdy(inwmme, inwdde, inwyye)
format %td interviewend // date format
```

This didn't change how Stata calculates the date though: it just changes the output, as far as I could understand.

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain exactly what "too large" means here, or what working with "actual dates" rather than numeric dates would mean. For calculating splines you must have a numeric representation of the date variable!

The display format is indeed irrelevant to what is stored, as was discussed at more length in [this paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1201200415).

I would simply set up your own date variable.

Your dates span the interval of a few months in 2016:

```
. di %td 20695 " " %td 20808
29aug2016 20dec2016
```

Set up a new date variable that is say your variable minus 20694. The only problem I can foresee is getting good axis labels for any graphics.

```
. gen newdate = olddate - 20694
```

Then to get intelligible axis labels you can define say

```
. label define mylabel 4 "1 Sept" 34 "1 Oct" 65 "1 Nov" 95 "1 Dec" 
. label val newdate mylabel
```

and ask for axis labels using an option

```
xla(4 34 65 95, valuelabel)
```

The device can easily be extended to add axis labels for key dates or say 15 Sept, 15 Oct, 15 Nov, 15 Dec.